Geothermal: Energy output calculations for a very large heat exchanger
Using deep wells as heat exchangers to extract geothermal energy has recently emerged as a concept. It can be visualized as a long (2000 m) vertical tube with an inner diameter of 162 mm (the outer pipe diameter is 177.8 mm, made of N-80 grade steel). Inside is another tube with a 73 mm outer diameter and 62 mm inner diameter, made of J-55 grade steel. Theoretically, there shouldn't be any contact between the tubes, and the inner tube is placed more or less in the center. The inner tube is 10 meters shorter than the outer tube and has an open hole at the bottom.
For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that we have fresh water in the circulation contour.
At a depth of 2000 m, we have a temperature of 70 degrees C and a geothermal gradient of 3 degrees C per 100 m. Hence, the temperature decreases by 3 degrees C every 100 m as we go up. We can have two circulation modes:
Direct: water goes down through the inner pipe and returns up between the inner and the outer pipes.
Reverse: water returns up through the inner pipe.
Question 1: Which flow is optimal from a thermodynamic point of view?
Question 2: What circulation rates (m³/day or l/s) can we have in both cases? What incoming temperature (hotter) can we have at the surface? How much can we take (20-30-etc degrees) in the secondary contour? What energy quantities in Watts can we have here?
Where I should start with my calculations? The biggest problem I can see is that water, which flows down will be cooling the up-flowing water and vice versa.

So if the water starts at 70 deg C at the bottom, it looses 60n deg C by the time it gets to the top. Just dig down 2 metres and get 5 to 8 deg C...

the rate will be dependent on how much heat the ground can transfer into the water and what temperature you want the output.  A million liters per second might give you the same heat but only a 2 degree temperature increase, which is worthless.  Also this is extremely far from new.

@SolarMike, that's right, but I'm searching second life chances for depleted oil wells :)

You are going to want to pump the water down the outside, what you call Reverse.  If you do that, "cold" water will be exposed to the 10C external, followed by 20C, etc. until it gets to the bottom and it is exposed to 70C external.  As the water goes up the inner pipe, it will cool off, losing heat to the outer pipe.  This is somewhat akin to a counter flow heat exchanger.
If you ran the water down the middle and up the outside, the "cold" water would be exposed to 70C external followed by 60C, etc. to 10C, possibly losing energy to the outside.
Without knowledge of the heat capacity of the outside (how much heat can be extracted) and how fast the heat can be transferred to the inside, it is impossible to give numbers in terms of watts, etc. that are more than educated guesses.
Meanwhile, that never stopped me.
The inner pipe has a diameter of about 2 1/2 inches. From this site, a flow of 10 liters per second through a 2 1/2 PVC pipe (which is smoother than steel) would have a pressure drop of about $2.77\times 10^6$ pascals over 2000 meters. Pumping water down with about 3 MPa, a not unheard of pressure, will give you flow and not blow up the pipe at the bottom.
The heat capacity of water is 4200 J/kg and a liter of water weights about 1 kg.  A flow of 10 liters per second will give 42,000 joules for each degree temperature rise. With a heat source is 70C and a sink of 20C, that would be
$50 degrees \times 42,000 joules/degree = 2.3 \times 10^6 joules /second$ which is equal to 2.1 megawatts.
This is ignoring the pressure drop on the return and assuming perfect heat transfer and infinite heat capacity underground.
And there is also the "minor" problem of turning the low grade heat into something useful.  If you have a process that can use maybe 60C water, you are all set. To turn it into electricity, you run into those annoying laws of thermodynamics.
